# Question about the boundary of a set in point set topology

Tags: general-topology

I came across a question in regards to the boundary of a set.  The question is follows:

The boundary of a set A is closed if and only if A is the union of a closed and an open set.

The definition of boundary and frontier of a set are respectively defined as:  $\partial A$ = $A\setminus\mathring A$ and $Fr A=$$\partial A\cup\partial (X\setminus A)$, with $A$ being a subset of a topological space $X.$

I tried to derive it using various properties of open, closed and boundary of a set.  But I am not having any success. I am wondering if anyone have seen this before and show me how to solve it.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\implies$:

Let $\partial A$ be closed. Since $A= A \setminus A^ \mathrm{o} \cup A^ \mathrm{o} = \partial A \cup A^ \mathrm{o}$ we know that $A$ is the union of a closed and an open set.

$\Longleftarrow$:

Let $A= O \cup C$ where $O$ is an open set and $C$ is a closed set. Then $\partial A = A \setminus A^\mathrm{o}= (O \cup C) \setminus (O \cup C^\mathrm{o})= C \cap \underbrace{(O \cup C^\mathrm{o})^c}_{\text{closed}}$. Since the intersection of closed sets is closed we know that the boundary is closed.

Side note: I am used to the boundary being defined as $\partial A=\overline{A} \setminus A^\mathrm{o}$, so I was a little puzzled to read your statement at first (boundaries as in my defintion are always closed).